# Explain Hashed page tables in operating system

Tags: operating-systems, hash, hash-tables, virtual-memory, paging

I have a difficult time understanding hashed page tables used in virtual memory management. Here is picture of the slide that I am referring to:

[image: Hashed page table]

[image: Flow chart]

I understand that p is hashed and then the hash is checked in the page table for a match. What is elements referring to here? Is it the page table entry? What does chain mean and where is virtual page number located?

Can someobody help me understand the flow chart? Thanks

Comment: The element *is* a page table entry (tag, the PTE proper, and a pointer/reference to the next element matching that hash value). The chain is a singly linked list for handling hash conflicts. The VPN (usually compressed by exploiting the hash table indexing bits) is used as a tag and is stored with the PTE and next pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Definitions (What's with the symbols?)

In the diagram, we have these guys:

- Virtual Page Number (VPN): `p`, `q`
- Page Frame Number (PFN): `r`
- Offset: `d`
- Hash Function: `h(x)`
- Hashed Page Table with schema `(key, VPN, PFN, Pointer to next entry with key)` for each entry in the table

It so happens that `h(p) = same_key` and `h(q) = same_key`. There is hash collision. Both `p` and `q` are hashed to the `same_key`.

This is resolved by chaining the entry with `VPN = q` to the entry with `VPN = p`. Chaining means to use the `Pointer` field in the entry with `VPN = q` to **point** to the entry with `VPN = p`.

## Workflow (How the system works)

Operating system (OS) grabs `p` from the CPU, and performs `h(p)` to get `same_key`.

OS looks up the first entry in the Hashed Page Table with `key = same_key` and checks `p` against the first entry's `VPN` field. It checks `p` against `q`. This is incorrect.

OS uses the `Pointer` in the first entry to find the second entry. It knows that the second entry has the same `key = same_key`, because the Page Table is constructed this way. OS checks `p` against the seond entry's `VPN` field. It checks `p` against `p`. This is correct. Bam. Kill confirmed.

OS knows that this is the correct entry it is looking for. It grabs `PFN` from the second entry. It grabs `r`. `r` is the correct physical frame number that corresponds to virtual page number `p`.

OS uses `r` to look for the physical frame it wants in physical memory, and looks for the exact word wanted which is offset by `d` within frame `r` in physical memory. OS grabs the contents of the word and we're done.

#### Source: Dave Johnson's COMP 421 (Rice University CS Dept)